# Input file in chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, chapters

I cannot figure out how to import a file in a chapter title:

```
\chapter{\input{"Introduction.txt"}}
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{\input{"Introduction.txt"}}{Introduction}}
```

Both of these fail with

> Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the contents of `Introduction.txt`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I will try to format the question properly next time. Thanks for editing this one and for the pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\input` is a fragile command so needs `\protect` here, although it seems a very strange thing to do, it works

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{introduction.txt}
Introduction
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\protect\input{Introduction.txt}}
zzz

\end{document}
```